# C# check driver for file types followed by action

Tags: c#, file, visual-c#-express-2010

So basically i am making an app that will sync file types is different ways, I want to search the whole of a logical Drive for example `C:\` for all text files.How ever once i find all the text files i want to apply an action for example move all text files to one location or email all text files to the users email.

I have found this code from a past [Stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) post

```
 public List<string> Search()
{
    var files = new List<string>();
    foreach (DriveInfo d in DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(x => x.IsReady))
    {
        try
        {
            files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(d.RootDirectory.FullName, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Log(e.Message); // Log it and move on
        }
    }

    return files;
}
```

But what i want to know is how do i do somthing when i find the files ?

Comment: Um... Iterate through the contents of the returned List, and do something for each file in the List?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted looks like it should fill `List<string> files` with `strings` representing names of files that have a `.txt` extension.

It should be as simple as iterating over the value returned from the function and doing as you please with them.

This code should (untested) check for a target directory, create it if it doesn't exist, and then copy each file returned from `Search()` to the target path.

```
List<string> results = Search();

String targetPath = "C:/TargetDirectory/";
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);

foreach (string aFileStr in results)
{
    String sourceFile = aFileStr;
    String destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, Path.GetFileName(aFileStr));
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do a foreach on the list of strings that that function returns.

Comment: Sorry to be annoying,but for reference can i get an example code segment please :)

Comment: See @AnotherUser 's post, exactly what i would have posted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand you correctly. If you just want to know how to process your filelist, you could for instance do the following:

```
var filelist = Search();
foreach (var s in filelist) {
     string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
     string dest = System.IO.Path.Combine("c:\\tmp", fn);
     System.IO.File.Copy(s, dest, true);
}
```

which will copy all files in filelist to c:\tmp and overwrite files with equal filename.